# Javascript function into input

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form name="test_form">
    <input id="demo" type="text" value=""> 
</form>



<button onclick="data()">GO</button>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");  
function data()
  {
    x.innerHTML="TEST"; 
  }
</script>
```

I am trying to input JavaScript function into input field but I've got a problem with that, nothing is happening, any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: First of all your code doesn't do what you think it does. You do not use .innerHTML to change the value of an input tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x.innerHTML="TEST";
```

should be

```
x.value="TEST";
```

Comment: @Neal, Please enlighten as to what else is wrong. I think this is the main thing. Even if it isn't, I don't think this warrants a downvote, it surely fixes the OP's problem. http://jsfiddle.net/Fan5v/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

function data()
{
  var x=document.getElementById("demo");
  x.value="TEST"; 
}
</script>
<form name="test_form">
  <input id="demo" type="text" value=""> 
</form>
<button onclick="data();">GO</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vdAY7/